# use fastify to download big files as multipart

Tags: node.js, fastify

I have a code that download big objects from S3 using multipart download. I am working now on a microservice that will hide all the s3 operations and in the future will give me the flexibility to change to any object store.I have created a nodejs service using fastify, how can I add the support of multipart download using fastify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite the parts logic of AWS-S3 service in server and client side too.

The [GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html) accepts the `Range`
header that will limit the download of that piece of file.

So the client need to know how many pieces compose a file, using the [ListParts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listParts-property)
API usually. Then it can call the [GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)
with the range parameter:

```js
 var params = {
  Bucket: "examplebucket", 
  Key: "SampleFile.txt", 
  Range: "bytes=0-9"
 };
 s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {...
```

So your Fastify server should proxy at latest those 2 services to let the client download
simultaneously many pieces of the file and then merge them.